# What are the common severity marker characters for log files?

Tags: logging, error-logging

In the olden days, when log files were huge and hard disks were small, programs used a single character as the first character in a line to mark the severity of the log entry, similar to this:

```
! This is an error message
+ This is a warning message
: This is a normal message
# This is a debug message
  I don't know about this (no marker character)
```

Depending on the program the line also contained a time stamp directly after that character.

This example is made up, I don't remember which characters were actually used. I am only pretty sure of the "!" being used for errors.

I could not find any description of a log file that uses this kind of syntax. Is there a Standard for this? If yes, were is it described?

I could make up my own system easily but if there is a standard I would like to use it.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Is this question unclear? Or not useful? I certainly tried to google first.

Answer (score 0):

Since apparently nobody has an answer, here are the characters I ended up using:

- '-' Dump,
- '+' Trace
- '?' Debug
- ' ' (space) Info
- '$' Warning
- '!' Error

They loosely correspond to those that the Fidonet mailer FrontDoor used in its log files.